# Huawei Push Kit Flutter : Push.getToken() returns ResultCode -5

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

When I look at the documentation, it tells that -5 is related to proguard rules so I added them as mentioned here.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/error-code-0000001050255690-V5

android/proguard-rules.pro

```
## Flutter wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**

## HMS Core SDK
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.huawei.hianalytics.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.updatesdk.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hms.**{*;}
```

android/app/build.gradle part:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Here is the code init and get token part:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  String _token = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    HwAds.init();
    initPush();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initPush() async {
    if (!mounted) return;
    Push.getTokenStream.listen(_onTokenEvent, onError: _onTokenError);
  }

  void _onTokenEvent(String event) {
    print('onTokenEvent');
    _token = event;
    showResult("TokenEvent", _token);
  }

  void _onTokenError(Object error) {
    print('onTokenError');
    PlatformException e = error;
    showResult("TokenErrorEvent", e.message);
  }

  void showResult(String name, [String msg = "Button pressed."]) {
    print('$name: $msg');
    if (msg.isNotEmpty) Push.showToast(msg);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Interstitial Ad Page'),
              onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/interstitialPage'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get token'),
              onPressed: ()=> Push.getToken(''),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using cloud debugging and model name is P40. I created a release apk, chose data storage location, provided SHA256, enabled Push Kit, updated agconnect-services after enabling push kit. Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add

```
-keep class com.huawei.hms.flutter.** { *; }
```

to your proguard-rules.pro

Check this official sample

https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin/blob/master/flutter-hms-push/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: I updated my proguard-rules.pro same as sample project but still getting ResultCode -5 error message.

Comment: @FigenGüngör Could you please provide your Logcat logs?

Comment: Here are the exported logs after getToken is called: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HH33KWr3thfYo8IuYuIqfnfsqu1kbKILNTNW7rZr0z0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @FigenGüngör It's a confusing issue. Please try to add ```minifyEnabled true``` and see if it works.

Comment: Tested with minifyEnabled true but didn't change the error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer can help

Try calling getToken just to generate token, and then getTokenStrem, this works for me

> ```
> Push.getToken('');
>
> final token = await Push.getTokenStream.first;
> ```

Nos i'm just confused what should i have to send in Scope, and not an empty storing

Comment: So do you have an answer or still wondering?

Comment: This returns string token, like fcm, just scope idk how to use
This token works sending push in Huawei console and by http